# Python, UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 1718: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, encoding

I am trying a simple parsing of a file and get the error due to special characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python                                                                                                                 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-                                                                                                               

infile = 'finance.txt'
input = open(infile)
for line in input:
  if line.startswith(u'▼'):
```

I get the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 1718: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Solution?

Comment: You can use `codecs` too for open file with `utf-8` or `utf-16` encoding

Answer (score 5):

You need to provide the encoding. For example if it is `utf-8`:

```
import io

with io.open(infile, encoding='utf-8') as fobj:
    for line in fobj:
        if line.startswith(u'▼'):
```

This works for Python 2 and 3. Per default Python 2 opens files assuming no encoding, i.e. reading the content will return byte strings. Therefore, you can read only `ascii` characters. In Python 3 the default is what
`locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` returns, in many cases `utf-8`. The standard `open()` in Python 2 does not allow to specify an encoding. Using `io.open()` makes it future proof because you don't need to change your code when switching to Python 3.

In Python 3:

```
>>> io.open is open
True
```

Comment: Technically, Python 2 opens files assuming no encoding and returns byte strings.  Python 3 opens files assuming `locale.getpreferredencoding()` (which may not be `utf8`) and returns Unicode strings, but allows an encoding to be specified.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Open your file with the correct encoding, for example if your file is UTF8 encoded with Python 3:

```
with open('finance.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in input:
        if line.startswith(u'▼'):
            # whatever
```

With Python 2 you can use `io.open()` (also works in Python 3):

```
import io

with io.open('finance.txt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for line in input:
        if line.startswith(u'▼'):
            # whatever
```